# Algorithm to get each intervals estimated length on an ECG - Python

Tags: python

If I have something like this:

[image]

That's a graphical representations of an ECG exam.

But they could be super different, like this one:

[image]

And so, to find each Peaks, like R, T, etc, I created the intervals where they could be found. But with every exam those change, and my question is how do I make an algorythm that'll work with any non corrupted ecg graph.

This is what I got:

```
qInterval = averageOfRInterval * 250 / 926  # Multiplied numbers are default for each interval and 926 is the
sInterval = averageOfRInterval * 250 / 926  # correspondent to 100% of the Interval.
tInterval = averageOfRInterval * 300 / 926
pInterval = averageOfRInterval * 400 / 926
```

It'll work for some graphs, but not all.

Is that another way? Or is my algorythm correct but just needs a little adjusting?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to detect the peaks you can use `peakutils` module of python. Here is the documentation - https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/peakutils/latest/peakutils.pdf

Like `peakutils.peak.indexes(y, thres=0.3, min_dist=1, thres_abs=False)` will give you the index of peaks with peak amplitude higher than threshold 0.3 and the minimum distance between them will be 1.

You can also use `plotly` for visualizing the peak. Here are some examples - https://plot.ly/python/peak-finding/

Comment: The thing is that I want to detect each Peaks sperately, like r peak, q peak, t peak etc

Comment: Do you need the peak value? `peak.indexes()` will give you the peak values in a list.

Comment: I need the value and the position too. But the thing is I want to identify whether It is  an R Peak, a q Peak, a T peak, etc, so I can work with them.

Comment: Oh, that's an ECG signal and you want specific peaks. I can suggest you a research paper - https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282878749_P_and_T_peak_parameter_detection_in_ECG_signals . In most cases these kinds of situations need a good amount of research to find out the pattern, there is no fixed solution for these. You can use machine learning techniques for these kinds of peak detection.

Comment: I wanted an algorythm like the one that I made, that would calculate the peaks on all the graphs.